# modify key part of of the json using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Using Powershell how do I modify "/api/v1/user/Answers" under paths for json?. I would like to replace it with some other value like /abc/v1/xyz/Answers.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "host": "worktest.com",
    "paths": {
        "/api/v1/user/Answers": {...},
        "/api/v1/user/Assignments/GetUserAssignmentDetails": {...},
        "/user/Assignments/GetStatus": {...},
        "/Grades/GetGradesByProduct": {...}
    },
}

$content = Get-Content 'd:\temp\test.json'| ConvertFrom-Json

$content.paths.'/api/v1/user/Answers' # not sure where to go from here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following JSON:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "host": "worktest.com",
    "paths": {
        "/api/v1/user/Answers": {
          "answer1": "something",
          "answer2": "something else"  
        },
        "/api/v1/user/Assignments/GetUserAssignmentDetails": "value",
        "/user/Assignments/GetStatus": "value",
        "/Grades/GetGradesByProduct": "value"
    }
}
```

The following code copies the value of the key to newly-created one and then deletes the old key:

```bsh
$content = Get-Content 'test.json'| ConvertFrom-Json
# Which key to replace
$pathToBeReplaced = '/api/v1/user/Answers'
# Construct new key
$newPath = $pathToBeReplaced -replace '^/api','/abc'

# Create new property with proper value
$content.paths | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $newPath -Value $content.paths."$pathToBeReplaced"
# Remove old key
$content.paths.PSObject.Properties.Remove($pathToBeReplaced)
```

Now let's see the output:

```bsh
# Getting output
PS> $content.paths |fl

/api/v1/user/Assignments/GetUserAssignmentDetails : value
/user/Assignments/GetStatus                       : value
/Grades/GetGradesByProduct                        : value
/abc/v1/user/Answers                              : @{answer1=something; answer2=something else}
```